# Am I allowed e.g. to change my intention to pray asr after making an initial intention of praying maghrib during the salah?

Tags: salat

Let's say I started praying maghrib with a jama'a with the intention of praying maghrib, but as soon as I went into prayer, I remember that I didn't pray asr.
The question is:

**Am I allowed to change my intention to pray asr after making an initial intention of praying maghrib during the salah?**

Comment: This questions could have different answers according to madhabs: First you should know that you can change your intention! *But the point will be is it allowed to pray fard behind an imam with the intention of an other fard prayer* some madhabs will refuse it or regard it as invalid (As an Imam should be followed! some madhabs take this statement strictly, others not)! Then if you prayed maghrib or 'asr what will you have to do would be an other question!

Comment: Nice point @Medi Saif remarked. But fore more info. for the dear questioner, as Shi'i  (Shia) viewpoint, it is not wajib to do the Qaza just at that time of Maghrib Salah, haply: it is better if you say your maghrib prayers (Jama'a), then (or after Asha' prayer) you can do it. / Thus you'd better to do your Maghrib salah by the maghrib salah of the Jama'a .. then. Hope it be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
                    In the name of Allah, the compassionate, the merciful
```

In regard to your query as you inquired:

> Am I allowed to change my intention to pray asr after making an
>   initial intention of praying maghrib during the salah??

It is not wajib --obligatory-- to do the Qaza (of Asr prayer) just at that time of Maghrib Salah, haply: it is better if you say your maghrib prayers (Jama'a), then (or after Asha' prayer) you can do it. Or even you can do its Qaza tomorrow or later, but this is better to do it as soon as possible ... / Thus you'd better to do your Maghrib salah by the maghrib salah of the Jama'a... Then...